# double borders when columns stack in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I am getting a double border on the cross, when these two columns stack on top of the other two columns. I am using bootstrap.

```css
.border-col {
   border:1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 border-col"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 border-col"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 border-col"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 border-col"></div>
</div>
```

How do I avoid the double border? I have tried using the child selector, but cannot seem to get it exactly right.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the examples before are not considering the vertical, here is one example that might be better. its depended on css3.

```css
.border-col {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  border-bottom: none
}

.border-col:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: none;
}

.border-col:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
}

.border-col:last-child {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-col">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-col">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-col">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-col">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-col">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, works perfectly. There are no borders missing, and no double borders anywhere.

Comment: Hi, related question. Exactly the same style and HTML as original question; however this time, keep the borders as is, and apply space between them. Applying top/bottom margin works fine. Any left/right margin however makes the two columns stack.

Comment: Something came up with the first solution. It works fine until 482 px. At 481px and below, the bottom left box drops down. Reducing the default BS padding fixes this (padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;). However even when padding is set to zero, at even lower resolutions, the same thing happens again. Any fix other than the padding? I could go with a white border-right at low resolutions. This is also a fix, cos the background is also white, but anything else more accurate will be welcome!

Comment: As bootstrap instructs, we cannot put margins outside the cols or it breaks the structure of the columns. My suggestion is to work with padding inside the col instead. the way my guys usually work is to use the columns as grid-lines only and then to build the elements inside as much as possible as children elements. it prevents  you from having to deal with extra width and default functionality.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I would have had difficulty figuring out that BS allows top/bottom but not left/right, and that it was a hard coded feature. Yes you are right, using columns as grid lines only is a good idea. In this case though, I wanted the visual effect of having dashed grid lines, rounded, and separated with some space. I don't think that this can be accomplished with just the padding, even if I use box-sizing: content-box. Probably the only thing left is to use a dashed image border, if I would like to go in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
.border-col {
   border:1px dotted grey;
  border-bottom:0;
}
.border-col:last-child {
   border:1px dotted grey;
}
```

[PEN Here](https://codepen.io/pen)

Answer (score 0):

Use only one border for all the div's expect first div or last div that will help you to avoid the double border

```
.border-col {
   border:1px dotted grey;
   border-bottom: 0;
}

.border-col:last-child {
   border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```